# In the context of gambling, specifically poker, do you post a bet or place a bet?

Tags: word-usage, terminology, slang

In the context of poker a player places/posts bets. Two particular types of bets are the blinds.

I've seen "place a bet" and "post the small/big blind" but are the verbs interchangeable?

I understand that "to post" can mean "to announce or publish" something and I believe "to place a bet" is the more common expression, but can you "post a bet" or "place the small/big blind"?

Comment: I don't have expert knowledge on this, but in my circles, generally one would say **place** a bet, not **post**.  **Post your blind(s)** is a common phrase because it's a natural extension of English to describe how blinds are placed.  But apart from blinds, one would not describe a bet as being **posted**. (Rather, 'Placed,' 'called,' 'raised,' etc...)   ... Interesting question.

Comment: In poker, one _places a bet_.  _Post_ is not a poker term; it has to do with the necessities of online communication, and not with the game.

Comment: To clarify, the reason why I felt _post_ is a possibly valid verb to use with _bet_ is because it's used with _blind_, whether _post_ is used as a poker term specifically or a more general gambling term. I understand it might not be appropriate to say _post a bet_ but I'm looking for an explanation of why the two different verbs are applied to the two different types of bets.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some more research I reached the conclusion that the verb *post* is mostly used with [forced bets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betting_in_poker#Forced_bets), like blinds or the ante.

I wasn't able to find a clear origin of the word, but I believe [Ante-post betting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ante-post_betting) is worth mentioning as a possible etymology:

> In horse racing and greyhound racing, an ante-post bet is a bet placed before the horse/greyhound racing course's betting market has opened [...]
>   The ante in ante-post is derived from the Latin ante (meaning "before"), but the post is not the Latin post (meaning "after"). Instead, it is derived from the nineteenth century Betting Post, a stake that was traditionally fixed somewhere on the course ground like a sign-post to signal the beginning of fixed betting to bettors.

Comment: You can also post a poker stake, which has an entirely different meaning.